# Where should I start, models are there but... they aren't?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

working with backbone, I was seeing a problem where some data was being left blank, so I wrote this to try to see what was going on.

```
console.log('actions.models', this.model.actions.models)
console.log('actions.models.length', this.model.actions.models.length)
console.log('first actions.models', this.model.actions.models[0])
```

the output

```
actions.models [ Action ]
actions.models.length 0
first actions.models undefined
```

if I add a setTimeout of say 2 seconds to this code I get

```
actions.models [ Action ]
actions.models.length 1
first actions.models Action
```

I don't get how this could happen. I don't know where to start looking or even what would be helpful to post for you guys to look at.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the models via an Ajax function, like `fetch`? If so, you can't count on data being loaded until the Ajax function's callback is invoked, e.g.

```
actions.fetch {success: -> console.log actions.models.length}
```

Comment: They are being pushed from the server via websockets.

Comment: Same principle. WebSockets are non-blocking. There's a callback somewhere, and you can't count on the models being loaded until that callback is called.

Comment: The websocket data adds to a parent model and these events are bound to an add event on that parent. I assumed the add event wouldn't fire before the data was received -- if this isn't true how can I build in a callback in such situation?

Comment: Either way, thanks for the lead I will try to run some more tests.

Comment: You just said it: Rather than binding to the WebSockets callback directly, you just have to bind to `actions.on 'add'`.

Comment: So you're saying that from the `actions.on 'add'` callback, `actions.models.length` is 0?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but anyway.. When you dump objects to the console log, be aware of the fact that since objects are passed by reference, whatever you get from inspecting it in the log will be whatever the object ended up being. Assuming you want to log the state of an object you should probably try to serialize it when logging. For instance `console.log "mymodel: ", JSON.stringify(mymodel.attributes)`.

Also be aware that to access backbone models, you would typically use `name = mymodel.get('name')`, or for a collection `item = mycollection.get('someid')`.

If you post some testable code and what you are trying to accomplish, I'm sure somebody with a clue will be able to help you out.

Comment: I don't think the asynchronicity of `console.log` is the answer here, since `actions.models.length` will be passed by value rather than by reference (no `JSON.stringify` needed).